# JSON split in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

How we can split this in a single query, Any ideas or suggestions ?

```
{"_xxx8430yyy59_xx":{"label":"Campaign Codes"},"_zzz984ggg4110_zzz":{"label":"NL Discount Codes"},"_ttt9843hhh160_ttt":{"label":"OOP Discount Codes"},"_ddd984393lll3_ddd":{"label":"Influencer Codes (Offer)"} }
```

I have tried to do this in multiple statements , but was not successful.

```
WITH CTE AS(select *,  unnest(string_to_array(value, ',')) AS parts from config_data)
SELECT parts from CTE
```

Expected output as

```
ID                      label
_xxx8430yyy59_xx         Campaign Codes
_zzz984ggg4110_zzz        NL Discount Codes
_ttt9843hhh160_ttt        OOP Discount Codes
_ddd984393lll3_ddd        Influencer Codes (Offer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't string-split anything, you use the [JSON processing functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) that are built into postgres:

```
SELECT key as "ID", obj.value->>'label' AS label
FROM config_data,
jsonb_each(config_data.value::jsonb) AS obj(key, value)
```

You should also change the data type of the `value` column in your table to be `jsonb`/`json`, if you haven't already.